# how to set event listener to back button in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I need to set an event listener that will listen to the back button in the browser. I need to show `alert` after the user clicks on the back button.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read through [ask]. Hard to understand the current version and exactly what you want. That being said the back button is not accessible from inside the window

Comment: sorry for that , i edit it ^^

Comment: Well you can't tell how user is trying to leave page....only know that they are about to leave through unload events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for negative response.. its  my first question :\

i found this solution and its very useful >>

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">


                    window.onload = function () 
                    {
                        if (typeof history.pushState === "function") 
                        {
                            history.pushState("jibberish", null, null);
                            window.onpopstate = function () 
                            {
                                history.pushState('newjibberish', null, null);
                                // Handle the back (or forward) buttons here
                                // Will NOT handle refresh, use onbeforeunload for this.
                            };
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            var ignoreHashChange = true;
                            window.onhashchange = function () 
                            {
                                if (!ignoreHashChange) 
                                {
                                    ignoreHashChange = true;
                                    window.location.hash = Math.random();
                                    // Detect and redirect change here
                                    // Works in older FF and IE9
                                    // * it does mess with your hash symbol (anchor?) pound sign
                                    // delimiter on the end of the URL
                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                     ignoreHashChange = false;   
                                }
                            };
                    }
                }


</SCRIPT>
```